# How to upscale an image to match the screen size?

Tags: java, android

You can see my problem on the image below. I use sqlite database to provide the image to display it, so I can only provide one sise of the image, for the db size sake. The image is 480X550. This is emulator on 720x1280 xhdpi. I have no problems on lower resolutions of the screen. How to make the phone to scale the image up to the size of the screen? I don't care to much about the quality of the image after resizing. I don't want fullscreen, I just need it to upscale the image until it reaches the screen borders on the left and on the right.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you use same image on different screen sizes, and in high resolutions it can't fill the screen. best thing is to use different image sizes (in Alternative drawables folders)   based on screen size. please refer [this](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Handling-Multiple-Screen-Size-in-Android) document from Samsung, hope that will help.

Comment: As I said, I don't use  drawables folders for my images, I use SQLite database. And I can only have one size of the image. Is there a way to automatically upscale the image until it fills the screen horizontally?